# In order to get the Massacre achievement, do you need to kill all civilians as well?

Tags: achievements, monaco

The description for the Massacre achievement for Monaco on Steam says

> Kill everyone on a single mission

On some missions, there are civilians as well as guards that you can kill. Now I know you can just go to a mission that doesn't have any civilians and then just kill the guards, but that still leaves the question; is it mandatory to kill civilians as well as guards in order to get the Massacre achievement?

Comment: Logic follows that "everyone" would, theoretically, include civilians, but having never played the game, I don't know for certain.

Comment: @Unionhawk Yeah that's what I was thinking, but I wasn't 100% sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [developer](http://steamcommunity.com/app/113020/discussions/0/540736781177682789/?tscn=1395879903), yes you must kill civilians as well as guards in order to get the achievement. The easiest level to do this is Hijack at the Hairpin.